# Cannot play video created by OpenCV (using Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I tried to write a video from a sequence of images created by OpenCV. However I cannot open the videos after writing them. I guess there is a codec issue. I find it extremely difficult where the error exactly comes from. Here is my code:

```
    Size size = Size(vecOfMats[0].rows,vecOfMats[0].cols);
    int codec = CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X');

    VideoWriter videoWriter;
    videoWriter.open(outputFilename,codec,15.0,size,true);

    for(int z=0; z < vecOfMats.size(); z++)
    {
        videoWriter.write(vecOfMats[z]);
    }
    videoWriter.release();
```

I also tried all of these codecs without success (either OpenCv could not find the codec or the video could not be opened):

```
int codec = CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1');   // = MPEG-1 codec
int codec = CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G');   // = motion-jpeg codec - cannot be played by VLC
int codec = CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2');// = MPEG-4.2 codec - not found
int codec = CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3');// = MPEG-4.3 codec - not found
int codec = CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X');// = MPEG-4 codec - cannot be played by VLC
int codec = CV_FOURCC('U', '2', '6', '3');// = H263 codec - must have w/h = 4
int codec = CV_FOURCC('I', '2', '6', '3');// = H263I codec - not found
```

I even took the codec of a video opened via OpenCV previously (without success):

```
string filename = "/path/to/the/video/myVideo.avi";
VideoCapture capture(filename);
int ex = static_cast<int>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC));             // Get Codec Type- Int form
char EXT[] = {(char)(ex & 0XFF) , (char)((ex & 0XFF00) >> 8),(char)((ex & 0XFF0000) >> 16),(char)((ex & 0XFF000000) >> 24), 0};// Transform from int to char via Bitwise operators
cout<<"Codec: "<<ex<<endl;
VideoWriter videoWriter;
videoWriter.open(outputFilename,ex,15.0,size,true);
```

I'm not even sure if the problem lies with my OpenCV or my Ubuntu :/. 
(I tried to open them using the default video player and vlc)

Comment: You don't say in your question, do you definitely have a [codec](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php) installed?

Comment: I compiled ffmpeg from source before compiling OpenCV (ffmpeg -version says that I have ffmpeg 2.3.3 installed).I compiled OpenCV from source (version 2.4.5) and ccmake says that it definitely found ffmpeg. I'm not sure which codecs are used by vlc and the videoplayer but since I can encode videos I thought I should be able to decode them in the same format (as in the second coding example)

Answer (score 1):

Since I gave up on writing videos using Opencv I just want to mention how I resolved my problem. After saving every image as a png file, I'm using ffmpeg from linux command line to write the sequence of images as a video.

Pictures are named sequentially like this:
00001.png,
00002.png,
00003.png,
[…]

Then I use this command

> ffmpeg -i %5d.png -vcodec mpeg4 test.avi